# A-Frame link traversal support

Tags: virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

In [A-Frame FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-add-links-to-my-scene), it is written that:

> Link traversal support was introduced in the WebVR 1.0 API and A-Frame
>   0.3.0. There is a link component that can trigger navigation and built-in support for knowing whether the user is navigating from
>   another WebVR experience.

However, it seems there is no entry in [A-Frame Docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/introduction/) about this link component. 
How could one use such a component to trigger link traversal ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, that is a mistake. Built-in link traversal and documentation has not yet been introduced as we improve link traversal experiences in the WebVR specification and the browsers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This has just been introduced in AFrame 0.6
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Edit: 
Here's the page for it:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/link.html